# How to use the return value of function in its own callback function?

Tags: javascript, callback

I have this code:

```
$('#from_country').change(function () {
    var selected_from = $(this).find('option:selected');
    var country = roaming_prices_from(selected_from.val(), function () {
        console.log(country);
    });
```

How can I use the return value of `roaming_prices_from` inside of its own callback function?

Comment: Passing the value as argument to the callback is the responsibility of  `roaming_prices_from`. You must change this function, or don't use the function as callback (i.e. `callback(roaming_prices_from(selected_from.val()));`)

Comment: Why can't you just pass the `country` to callback method when invoking it from `roaming_prices_from` method?

Comment: like such: `var country = roaming_prices_from(selected_from.val(), function (country) {
        console.log(country);
    });` ? This dosnt seem to work, but if this is correct. Then I might have a fault somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by passing the returning value of your function as a callback parameters ,

```
$('#from_country').change(function () {
    var selected_from = $(this).find('option:selected');
    var country = roaming_prices_from(selected_from.val(), function (xCountry) {
        console.log(xCountry);
    });
});
```

but to do this you have to pass a value inside your `roaming_prices_from` function

we will assume that the function `roaming_prices_from` will be as following :-

```
function roaming_prices_from(value, callback) {
    .....
    callback(returnedValue);
    .....
    return returnedValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assume that `roaming_prices_from` will resolve with the country value, i.e that function will have `Promise.resolve(country)`, which then means your callback (that prints out country) will receive `country` as a paramter